# JQuery Autocomplete - Three Source Files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I need to change the source file based on what radio button ( 3 choices ) the user chooses on the same page up higher on the form...

```
source: "includes/items_<?php echo $movie_group_a ?>.php", 
source: "includes/items_<?php echo $movie_group_b ?>.php",
source: "includes/items_<?php echo $movie_group_c ?>.php",
```

any idea on how to do this

// JQUERY AUTOCOMPLETION

```
$(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: "includes/items_<?php echo $movie_group_a ?>.php",
        minLength: 1, //search after one characters

        focus: function(event, ui) {
                $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
        },

        change: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                     alert("You must select an item from the drop-down list.");
                     $("#search").val('');
                     $("#search").focus();
                return false;
                }
         },

         select: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('#search').val(ui.item.value);
                this.value = ui.item.label;
             // $('#item1').val(ui.item.value);

                $('#item1').val(ui.item.fielda);


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hassan ALi - i tried this - it does not work

Answer (score 0):

create a function which contain the autocomplete functionality.

```
 function autocomplete(filename){    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
            source: filename,
            minLength: 1, //search after one characters

            focus: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
            },

            change: function(event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                         alert("You must select an item from the drop-down list.");
                         $("#search").val('');
                         $("#search").focus();
                    return false;
                    }
             },

             select: function( event, ui ) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $('#search').val(ui.item.value);
                    this.value = ui.item.label;
                 // $('#item1').val(ui.item.value);

                    $('#item1').val(ui.item.fielda);


            }
        });
    }
```

then call it on conditional bases like

```
$(".radio-buttion").click(function(){
if($(this).val()=="url"){
autocomplete("some url");
}else {
autocomplete("some other url");
}
});
```